# Where do Sass arguments/variables come from?

Tags: sass

I'm learning Sass (and JavaScript as well). I'm a bit confused on the variables used in arguments when writing a mixin. In the code below, after the mixin name we have the arguments, which I understand are variables ($image, $direction). What I'm confused about is - I believe (for example) $image and $direction are not random names/values - are these what they call SassExpressions? And is there a library or list of these somewhere? Does $direction refer to flex-direction? And $image refers to background image? Are these just CSS properties but with a shorthand? Sorry for the very newb question.

```
@mixin replace-text($image, $direction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are SASS variables. You can define any variables basically almost anywhere in SASS file, example:

```
$base-color: #c6538c;
$border-dark: rgba($base-color, 0.88);

.alert {
  border: 1px solid $border-dark;
}
```

Example comes from official SASS documentation regarding variables: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables

Comment: I see - so those are simply containers and can be named anything you want, just like in JavaScript. Thank you!

Comment: Yes of course, and if you want, you can also store them in a separate file and import it on demand anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, so powerful!